# Websphere MQ C++ client crashes in VS2013- library/linker issues?

Tags: winapi, dll, ibm-mq, visual-studio-2013

I just upgraded a project to VS2013 from VS2010 and now it crashes whenever I send a message via MQ, yet it worked fine under VS2010.

I suspected it was something to do with VS2013, so I built one of the demo apps that comes with MQ - imqwrld.cpp which is a simple "hello world" app.

This code alone is enough for the debug runtime library to throw an exception:

```
 #include <imqi.hpp> // WebSphere MQ C++
 int main ( int argc, char * * argv ) {

    ImqQueue * p = new ImqQueue();
    delete p;
    return 0
 }
```

when the ImqObject is deleted, the c rtl detects memory corruption.

I suspect it is because of DLL hell. The MQ dlls have a dependency on msvcr80.dll and my program uses a different version of the library - msvcr120d.dll.

Any suggestions on how I can solve this? I'm using MQ client 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a current release (up to and including 7.5) bug/restriction - the compiler that MQ produces its C++ libraries from, and the Visual Studio 2012+ compilers are apparently binary incompatible. You cannot solve nor workaround this other than to use the C or .NET API's depending on what you are trying to do...

As @John M Gant commented below, [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27027462#Windows_Compiler_ww) is the official support page from IBM. BTW, it looks like MQ Series 8.0 [is supported](http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqTabViewDetails?osPlatform=spcrAllValues&dsrType=tsr&deliverableId=1397738222071&productName=WebSphere%20MQ%208.0.0.1&prereqId=1346156759155&prereqName=Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%202012&capName=Compilers%20and%20Languages&isDUOnly=false&isMandatory=false&osPlatforms=Windows&duComponentIds=Desktop_FAB455F0C62C11E3B368206A22DC22DB%7CServer_FAB0FA90C62C11E3B368206A22DC22DB%7CServer_FAAD7820C62C11E3B368206A22DC22DB%7CServer_FAAE1460C62C11E3B368206A22DC22DB%7CServer_FAB03740C62C11E3B368206A22DC22DB%7CAgent%2FEnd-point_FAB392A0C62C11E3B368206A22DC22DB%7CAgent%2FEnd-point_FAB2F660C62C11E3B368206A22DC22DB%7CAgent%2FEnd-point_FAB1E4F0C62C11E3B368206A22DC22DB) for C++ in VS2012

Comment: Yeah, I tried 7.5 too. Where did you hear this? Are you definately sure the c version of the API works?

Comment: It looks like MQ is built with VS2005 judging from the dependency on msvcr80.dll. I suspect it is to do with memory allocations mixed up between VS2013's RTL and VS2005 RTL - when it crashes the call stack is totally fubar! I have managed to get my code to work... after some tweaks with the way I create the MQ objects, but from what you say, maybe its a crash just waiting to happen... I probably could port my code to use the C api easily enough though...

Comment: I know about this issue because I helped debug it :-) You are also right in that the product is built on 2005 at the moment. I am 100% sure the C api works, and also pretty certain the C++ issue cannot be worked around. FWIW calling the C api is far better for you long term, as the C++ api is stabilized.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you think the C API works? Have you had an official response from IBM on this? I thought it did too, then after a few inconsequential changes to my code it stopped working. This is exactly the same behavior I got with the C++ API (which I actually had working after tweaking the way I instantiated the MQ objects). I'm not meaning to sound rude, I just don't want to waste any more time trying to get this to work with VS2013...

Comment: Cant say for VS 2013, but 2012 definitely does (as far as discovered by testing so far). To the best of my knowledge the C api works, and the same problem doesnt exist because C has a defined (by standard) memory layout for its memory. Do you have a sample app which exhibits the problem you are seeing you could put somewhere for me to test and I dont mind taking a look

Comment: Thanks for the offer... as I said above, I got the C++ API to work when I instantiated the MQ objects using new, rather than declaring them in my class header. My problem in the C API is peculiar, as I managed to open the queuemanager and send queue and even send a message. Then, after a few changes that didn't touch any of the MQ code I started seeing my MQCNO structure corruped after calling MQCONNX... anyway, I'm going to park it for now. If I can knock up a sample app I'll post the details here. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what my issue was, but after a rebuild I got the C API working... thanks!

Comment: "Have you had an official response from IBM on this?"  He *is* IBM.  Works on the WMQ dev team.  Responses at this level don't get any more authoritative.

Comment: We submitted a PMR to IBM and were told that the VS2012 compiler is known not to work with the MQ C++ library. They referred us to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27027462#Windows_Compiler_ww

Comment: Ha! Well, that certainly beats trying to get a response out of IBM via official channels. Stack Overflow FTW!