# Connecting mq client to mq server with encrypted channel using C++ API

Tags: c++, ssl, ibm-mq

I have a legacy app accessing MQ Server from an MQ Client using the C++ API. How is this API used to add encryption over the Server Connection Channel? I can't find a location where the certificate is provided to the imqChannel object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide any code that is not working to help you with so I can provide only some general direction.

You specify the cipher like this:

```
pchannel->setSslCipherSpecification("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256");
```

You can specify the location of the `kdb` and `sth` file like this:
(note in this example it would expect to find two files, `/tmp/key.kdb` and `/tmp/key.sth`)

```
manager.setKeyRepository("/tmp/key");
```

You can also specify the location of the key repository non-programmatically using the `mqclient.ini` or setting the `MQSSLKEYR` environment variable, if you are interested in these options comment and I'll expand this answer.

Comment: There was no code because there was no attempt to write any code because I had no idea how to start: manager.setKeyRepository was the missing piece. We were investigating the non-programmatic version but the stumbling block there was the shared environment when we need to support different queue managers than we don't control. In any case, thanks for the info.

Comment: @jmucchiello the C++ API was stabilized by IBM with functionality at a level of MQ no longer supported.   They recommend you use the normal C API from C++.  You can put `mqclient.ini` in the present working directory of the process, MQ will look there first.   You can use this to have process specific configs

Comment: I'm well aware of the status of the C++ API. The 4th word of my question is "legacy" for a reason. Do you have a URL where that recommendation is made? I'd like to rip the C++ API out but because it's a legacy app... yada yada

Comment: Here are a few links: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030180_.htm, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101776/mq-jms-topic-equivalent-in-c-c/57103936#57103936, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062808/websphere-mq-c-client-crashes-in-vs2013-library-linker-issues/20085311#comment29961595_20085311, page 5 of https://share.confex.com/share/116/webprogram/Handout/Session8875/Whats%20New%20in%20MQ%20Family.pdf.